# How to make Excel VBA adjust the height of every n th row using a for loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I can't make Excel VBA adjust the row height depending on calculated row numbers. I calculate which rows need to be adjusted in height, using a for loop. Then I want to "select" those rows to make Excel adjust their height. (to ensure that they become hidden) However, the error "Application-defined or object-defined error" keeps coming back.

I tried several options where change the way the rows are defined. Using "with workbook" and stuff like that. I feel that only a minor change is required to the code I have, therefore I just provide this one.

```
Sub ChangeRowHeight()
Dim FindRowNumber As Long
Dim FindRow As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim m As Long

    Set FindRow = Range("A:A").Find(What:="Total Forecast 2022", LookIn:=xlValues)
    k = FindRow.Row


For i = 1 To (k - 9) / 9
        n = ((9 * i) + 1)
        m = ((9 * i) + 8)
        Rows("n:m").RowHeight = 1

    Next i

End Sub
```

I would like the VBA to first count the amount of Rows up to a particular item. (that works fine) And then determine n-times 8 rows in between that need to be adjusted in height (or hidden).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 100 Step 9
    Debug.Print i
Next i
```

will output

```
 1 
 10 
 19 
 28 
 37 
 46 
 55 
 64 
 73 
 82 
 91 
 100
```

So you can use `Rows(i)` to get every 9ᵗʰ row.

The rows between every 9ᵗʰ row can be accessed with

```
Debug.Print i + 1 & ":" & i + 8
```

Which would be

```
2:9
11:18
20:27
29:36
38:45
47:54
56:63
65:72
74:81
83:90
92:99
101:108
```

Note that if using `Find` you need **always** to specify the `LookAt` as `xlWhole` or `xlPart` otherwise Excel uses what ever was used before by the user (and you never know which one it is) because there is no default.

```
Dim FindRow As Range
Set FindRow = Range("A:A").Find(What:="Total Forecast 2022", LookIn:=xlValues LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Also you need to test if something was found after you used `find()`or you will run into an error:

```
If FindRow Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "'Total Forecast 2022' was not found!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = FindRow.Row

Dim iRow As Long
For iRow = 1 To LastRow Step 9
    Rows(iRow + 1 & ":" & iRow + 8).Hidden = True
Next iRow
```

Comment: Simple, strait forward and concise. plus

Comment: Thank you for the extensive explanation! This completely solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in a similar code. The final code became the following. I made a macro-button to hide/unhide every nth row (as described above). I had to avoid that the first few rows hide as well, so the loop after a few rows. 
Also, the macro ran too far (because I adjusted it), therefore, I substract 2 from the rows, to avoid this issue.

```
Sub Change_Row_Height()
Dim FindRow As Range
Dim iRow As Long

Set FindRow = Range("A:A").Find(What:="Total Forecast 2022", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If FindRow Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "'Total Forecast 2022' was not found!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = FindRow.Row

If Rows(10).Hidden = False Then
For iRow = 9 To LastRow - 2 Step 9
    Rows(iRow + 1 & ":" & iRow + 7).Hidden = True
Next iRow
ElseIf Rows(10).Hidden = True Then
For iRow = 9 To LastRow - 2 Step 9
    Rows(iRow + 1 & ":" & iRow + 7).Hidden = False
Next iRow
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Note you can reduce this to only one loop. Remove the `If … ElseIf … End If` and use `Rows(iRow + 1 & ":" & iRow + 7).Hidden = Not Rows(10).Hidden` in only one loop.

Answer (score -1):

lastrow = ws.usedrange.rows.count

ws.range("A1:A"&lastrow).rows.autofit